# Core Data: Modifying a Managed Object propagates to the rest of the UITableView records

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, managedobjectcontext

I am in the process of writing a Master/Detail CoreData RSS reader for the fun of it.

I use the following entities:
`Category 1->n Feed 0->n Post`

So in the left Pane of my UISplitView, there are the Feeds grouped by Category.
Choosing a Feed will fetch, then display its Posts in the right pane.

The right pane also contains a UITableView which uses 2 sorts of prototype cells:
`read` and `unread`.

`read` and `unread` depends upon the property `(NSDate *)read` of the corresponding `Post` ManagedObject: if it's `nil`, then it's to be displayed using an `unread` prototype cell.

Here's the code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *feedTableIdentifier = @"unread";
    Post *thepost = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDate *tmpDate=[NSDate date];
    if (thepost.read) {
        tmpDate=thepost.read;
        feedTableIdentifier = @"read";
    } else if (thepost.date) {
        tmpDate=thepost.date;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:feedTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:feedTableIdentifier];
    }
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1]).text = thepost.title;
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY";
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2]).text = [df stringFromDate:tmpDate];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3]).text = [self flattenHTML:thepost.excerpt];
    return cell;
}
```

Now, whenever I select a Post cell, I follow a segue which push a WebView pane onto the right pane. This WebView shows the contents of the relevant `Post.url` page.
In the same time, I will edit the current Managed Object `read` property  which I will set to the current NSDate.
I will then save the ManagedObjectContext and refetch the right pane's Feeds to reflect the new format:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    PostDetailController *webController = [[PostDetailController alloc] init];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowWebLink"]) {
        webController = [segue destinationViewController];
        webController.urlstr = ((Post *)sender).url;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Post *post=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowWebLink" sender:post];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    post.read = [NSDate date];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"[didSelectRowAtIndexPath] Error saving context: %@", error);
    }
    [self refetch];
}
```

Now, here's my problem:
When I pop the UIWebView and come back to the Feed list, the taped Post cell and all the following cells are now displayed as `read` the first time.
The second time, all the cells in the UITableView are shown as `read`.

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? I would like only the selected object to be marked as read...

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Could it come from this line in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

```
post.read = [NSDate date];
```

Should I replace it with:

```
[post setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"read”];
```

I am still confused by the dot notation vs `setValue`...

**EDIT 2:**

Nope :(
Just did the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The other data were not modified. I changed the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method the following way:

**WAS**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *feedTableIdentifier = @"unread";
    Post *thepost = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDate *tmpDate=[NSDate date];
    if (thepost.read) {
        tmpDate=thepost.read;
        feedTableIdentifier = @"read";
    } else if (thepost.date) {
        tmpDate=thepost.date;
    }
```

**IS**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *feedTableIdentifier = @"unread";
    Post *thepost = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDate *tmpDate=[NSDate date];
    if (thepost.read) {
        tmpDate=thepost.read;
        feedTableIdentifier = @"read";
    } else if (thepost.date) {
        tmpDate=thepost.date;
        feedTableIdentifier = @"unread";
    }
```

The `static`variable was affecting the other rows...